# JodaTime 1 or 2 Digit Timezone Offset

Tags: java, scala, jodatime

I have a string like this:

```
val str = "23 Jan 2015 14:30 (GMT+7)"
```

and I want to parse it to Joda's `DateTime`, with code approximately like this:

```
val format = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm ('GMT'Z)"
DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format).parseDateTime(str)
```

but of course it won't work because the `Z` format will read the timezone offset as `+0700`, but what I really want is `+7`. Is there any possible way to read this in JodaTime?

I do not have control on the String (it comes from an API) so I'll need to either post-process the string (which is not reliable) or use Joda's other format.

Thanks before.

Comment: Looks like your 3rd party service uses java8 cause java time formatter supports `O` conversion. If possible use it too and then transform to jodatime class.

Comment: Ok i'll try it and then post an answer if I got it right. Thanks.